# How to move items in a grid layout to center, if a row has less number of colums in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

This isn't a grid layout, I've used custom views to create this. Can anyone help me to create this with gridview . Does this even possible with GridLayout?

Comment: I think this behavior can be achieved with RecyclerView and custom GridLayoutManager if want to do it in one view not using any footers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might or might not be possible via `GridLayoutManager`, but there is no direct solution to get this using `GridLayoutManager`. I suggest you take a look at Flexbox layout manager here:

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

This is from Google and what you want can easily be done using it instead. You might need to play around with the properties a bit, but I think it can be done using the `justifyContent` property.

A rough code snippet would be something along the lines of

```java
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Thank you. this is great. But how can we set max columns to 4

Comment: @KalyanRevuru I think that might be opposite of  what you want then. You might have to search a bit because if fix have a fix column length then it is the same as `GridLayoutManager`. I am not sure about this, but to space out items `FlexboxLayout` is the only way unless you want to write your own custom view.